# Device tab bar icons washed out on iPhone 6 device but not simulator

Tags: objective-c, tabbar

On all simulators, my tab bar icons are beautifully done. They are detailed and cool. But when I actually test it on an iPhone 6, the tab bar icons are horribly washed out, for both the selected and unselected state! Tab bar icons on iPhone 5 look great. Here's a link that shows the phenomenon, shown as a screenshot of an iPhone 6 device: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IOCs4zlPAREzR01is1muecohFyhwKMK3K4pIidEP94E/edit?usp=sharing 
Note that on all device simulators the tab bar icons looks great. Has anyone experienced this and know how to fix it?

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot? (And not a Google docs document with a screenshot of a screenshot in a Pages document)

Comment: Looks like your phone has the “bold text” setting turned on, which causes UIImage to automatically apply a thickening effect that looks a lot like the one you’re seeing.